# How to use Map.merge for incrementing the counter as value?

Tags: java, merge, hashmap

I am trying to refactor a method that counts keys in HashMap in a more efficient way by implementing Map.merge(). How can I achieve it on the following code:

```
 public Map<Character, Integer> countCharacterUsage(String input) {
    Map<Character, Integer> characterToCountUsage = new WeakHashMap<>();
    for (char symbol : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (characterToCountUsage.containsKey(symbol)) {
            int symbolsCount = characterToCountUsage.get(symbol);
            characterToCountUsage.put(symbol, ++symbolsCount);
        } else {
            characterToCountUsage.put(symbol, 1);
        }
    }

    return characterToCountUsage;
}
```

Comment: Using merge() won't be more efficient.

Comment: If you really want to optimize: don't use toCharArray() because it clones the array. Use charAt() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
characterToCountUsage.compute(symbol, (k,v)-> v==null ? 1 : v+1);
```

Also with [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
characterToCountUsage.merge(symbol,1, (k,v)-> v+1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But just out of curiosity is it possible to the same with merge()?

Answer (score 1):

As per `merge()` behavior:

```
 V oldValue = map.get(key);
 V newValue = (oldValue == null) ? value :
          remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value);
 if (newValue == null)
   map.remove(key);
 else
   map.put(key, newValue);
```

proper way to do it is

```
characterToCountUsage.merge(symbol, 1, (oldValue, value) -> oldValue + 1);
```

But if you want to compress it even more, here is a one liner:

```
Map<Character, Integer> characterToCountUsage = input.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), newKey -> 1, (value1, value2) -> value1 + value2));
```